# Unknow KeyVault access policy from Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I am trying to add `KeyVault` and `access policy` from `Bicep`, but it is adding unknown in the access policy. If I add the same from the portal it is correctly added.

```
param systemLabel string = 'developer-3'

param vaultName string = 'developer-3'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param sku string = 'Standard'
param tenantId string = 'tenantId'
param objectId string = 'objectId'

@description('Tags that our resources need')
param tags object = {
  displayName: 'keyvault-${toLower(systemLabel)}'
}

param enabledForDeployment bool = true
param enabledForTemplateDeployment bool = true
param enabledForDiskEncryption bool = true
param enableRbacAuthorization bool = false
param softDeleteRetentionInDays int = 90

resource keyvault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-06-01-preview' = {
  name: vaultName
  location: location
  tags: {
    DisplayName: tags.displayName
  }
  properties: {
    tenantId: tenantId
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: sku
    }
    accessPolicies: []
    enabledForDeployment: enabledForDeployment
    enabledForDiskEncryption: enabledForDiskEncryption
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: enabledForTemplateDeployment
    softDeleteRetentionInDays: softDeleteRetentionInDays
    enableRbacAuthorization: enableRbacAuthorization
  }
}

resource accessPolicies 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2021-11-01-preview' = {
  name: 'add'
  parent: keyvault
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: tenantId
        objectId: objectId
        permissions: {
          secrets: [
            'get'
            'list'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The aim is to add both the keyvault and access policy from the Bicep.

Comment: For the `objectId` parameter what are you passing ? I would imagine it is not the correct value hence the `unknown` in the portal.

Comment: The objectId is the objectId of the service principle from app registration. It is neither application Id nor tenantId

Comment: should work tho. is it from same tenant ? could you check the deployment in azure portal t check that the desired objectId  is passed to the template ?

Comment: you are right. I found the right objectId from Export template of Keyvault in the portal. I added the policy from the portal and found the right Id and used it in Bicep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Thomas was right. I was using the wrong objectId though I copied the objectId from app registration service principle.

However, for anyone facing this issue. Add access policy to your keyvault from the portal (GUI) and then look for Export template in Automation section. The right object Id is there in the template.